# same value in first column sort by asc for other

Tags: mysql

Please help me to solve this:

```
create table Test(id integer, c1 varchar(100), c2 integer );
insert into Test(id, c1, c2) values(1, "Hello", 100);
insert into Test(id, c1, c2) values(2, "Hi", 500);
insert into Test(id, c1, c2) values(3, "Hello", 400);
insert into Test(id, c1, c2) values(4, "Hello", 300);
insert into Test(id, c1, c2) values(5, "Hi", 400);


select * from Test;

id  c1  c2
1   Hello   100
2   Hi  500
3   Hello   400
4   Hello   300
5   Hi  400
```

I want to **sort c2 by asc for similar c1 values**.
i.e.

```
id  c1  c2
1   Hello   100
5   Hi  400
4   Hello   300
3   Hello   400
2   Hi  500
```

I tried with `select * from Test order by c2 asc, c1;` but doesn't get the same result.

Comment: `select * from Test order by c1,c2`

Comment: @cars10m doesn't give the stated desired output, but then, the desired output and the statement of desired output seem to disagree.. Ashish, please clarify your question

Comment: If your questions are not clear then the answers either dont come or are no use to you

Comment: @cars10m that will not help. Please recheck those value insertion order and sorting sequence.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: I am using MySql 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run

`select * from Test order by c2 asc;`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a05638/4)

Comment: This will not give required output.

Comment: Your output seems confusing. Also `sort c2 by asc for similar c1 values` - I assume you mean that you want to sort values in `c2` column in Ascending order . Please tell me what is wrong in this [Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d07763/4)